# How to call .exe file with arguments from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe

I am trying to call an exe file from the node.js with 3 parameters. Getting error as

```
errno: 'ENOENT'
code: 'ENOENT'
```

I am using 64 bit windows 10 system . Here is the code that i am using currently

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var opt =function(){
      exec('file.EXE arg1 arg2 arg3', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });  
}
opt();
```

Comment: ENOENT indicates your file doesn't exist. Does calling it without any arguments result in different error?

Comment: It is in the same path @Subburaj

Comment: Without arguments it is opening the command prompt and asking the arguments one by one . I am able to run the .exe by the above code but something wrong with arguments . Now sure how to pass 3 parameters to it @Gavin

Comment: Where the file is and where the process is executed could be different. Try `__dirname + '/file.exe'` and see if that works?

Comment: Everything is in one directory for now @Gavin

Comment: @PritiranjanMishra Try for this `exec('file.EXE, ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']`

Comment: @Subburaj i am doing it like `exec('file.EXE', ['C:\\path\\to\\the\\file\\test.js', 'C:\\path\\to\\the\\file\\Map.csv', 'C:\\path\\to\\the\\file\\folderName']`  .

Comment: @Pritiranjan Mishra Any error or what???

Comment: It says "command line option syntax error. Type Command /? for Help"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate *file name* and *arguments*.

Syntax: **child_process.execFile(file[, args][, options][, callback])**

[Node Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var opt = function(){
      exec('file.EXE', ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"], function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });  
}
opt();
```

In the following example, I'm compiling Main.java using javac.exe.

here file name is javac.exe path and Main.java is argument.

[image: Example]

Comment: It gives the same error "command line option syntax error". Anything because of my windows machine ?

Comment: Give me some time, I'll try on my system.

Comment: Hi @Pritiranjan Mishra, See the example above, It's working fine. Could you please check your configurations one more time.